# Node.js - Promises and Callbacks Vs Sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I know about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and Callbacks. But I want to know,

Is it good or best practices to use sync modules like [Sync](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync), [synchronize](http://alexeypetrushin.github.io/synchronize/docs/index.html), etc., ?

What are the scenarios or areas I can use Sync and which scenarios I shouldn't ?

For example,

1. DB Operations
2. File read/write
3. HTTP Request(a.k.a CURL) to another server

**Note**: Currently I'm using [Sync](https://github.com/ybogdanov/node-sync) for DB Operations.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use Promises everywhere. It is a well supported standard "Promises A/+" https://promisesaplus.com/

I think everybody is moving that direction.